# Relational query with one result - SHOW FULL COLUMNS

Tags: yii2

I'm running the following query in my `actionView($id)`:

```
$model = User::find()->where(['id' => $id]->with('profile')->one();
```

and tried with this query with the exact same result:

```
$model = User::find($id)->with('profile')->one();
```

Dump from Yii Debugger:

```
#1  20:39:49.379    6.5 ms  SHOW    SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `user`
    C:\...\frontend\controllers\ProfileController.php (41)

#2  20:39:49.393    5.9 ms  SHOW    SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `profile`
    C:\...\frontend\controllers\ProfileController.php (41)

#3  20:39:49.375    0.8 ms  SELECT  SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `id`='8'
    C:\...\frontend\controllers\ProfileController.php (41)

#5  20:39:49.391    0.7 ms  SELECT  SELECT * FROM `profile` WHERE `user_id`=8
    C:\...\frontend\controllers\ProfileController.php (41)
```

This returns all the information i want, but it queries the full table for both User and Profile models, taking 6-7ms for each table (#1 and #2) in addition to the queries i would expect (#3 and #5). All queries are linked to the same line (41) in my profile controller.

Why are four queries run for this simple query, and what is the correct way to do a query like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1** and **2** queries are for loading attributes list for `User` and `Profile` models.

**3** - loading main `User` model with given id.

**4** - eager loading of all `Profile` related models to that one.

So there are no unnecessary queries, with `ActiveQuery` this is correct way of doing this.